# MySQL (MariaDB) swap column positions by index, NOT using after

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using the lastest version of MariaDB.

I have a simple table and want to swap positions of field 'test' with field 'gerge'. I can't retrieve the information of the whole column, which is why I can't use 'after'. (e.g. ALTER TABLE myTable MODIFY gerge INT AFTER id;).

I've googled abit but there seems to be no easy solution to this. I am looking for something like that:

```
ALTER TABLE CHANGE INDEX 2 TO 1
```

Does anyone tackeled this issue?

[image]

Comment: Why? Whats the purpose

Comment: _I can't retrieve the information of the whole column_ Explain please?

Comment: So this will not work? `ALTER TABLE xxxx MODIFY COLUMN gerge INT(1) AFTER id;`

Comment: OR `ALTER TABLE xxxx CHANGE COLUMN gerge gerge INT(1) AFTER id;`

Comment: The `#` "column" in your image is an artifact of the UI you are using.  The schema knows nothing about it.  So, do not consider `ALTER TABLE CHANGE INDEX 2 TO 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1.

dump the table data with column names. then restore it.

Option 2.

create table as select

Option 3.

Create new field, copy the data (update table set newf=oldf;)

Then drop old column and rename

Answer (score 1):

Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` to get the whole info on every column.  From that, formulate `ALTER TABLE ... AFTER ...`

Answer (score 1):

The `ordinal_position` of a column can be found in `information_schema.columns`.

You can generate the ALTER TABLE by reading that table, for example:

```
select concat('alter table `', c1.table_schema, '`.`', c1.table_name, 
  '` modify column `', c1.column_name, '` ', c1.column_type, 
  ' after `', c2.column_name, '`;') as _sql
from information_schema.columns as c1 
join information_schema.columns as c2 using (table_schema, table_name)
where c1.table_schema='test' and c1.table_name='mytable' 
  and c1.ordinal_position=2 and c2.ordinal_position=3;
```

Output given your table:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| _sql                                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| alter table `test`.`mytable` modify column `test` int(11) after `gerge`; |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

There's more work to be done, because my example doesn't handle `NOT NULL` or `DEFAULT` or extra column options or comments.